# Java mail attachment not working on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat6, jakarta-mail, tomcat5.5, apache-commons-email

I have an application which e-mails confirmations. The email part utilises Commons Mail API. The simple code which does the send mail is as shown below;

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;
...
// Create the attachment
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setURL(new URL("http://cashew.org/doc.pdf"));
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setDescription("Testing attach");
attachment.setName("doc.pdf");

// Create the email message
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("mail.cashew.com");
email.addTo("ben@cashew.org");
email.setFrom("lot@cashew.org");
email.setSubject("Testing);
email.setMsg("testing message");

// add the attachment
email.attach(attachment);

// send the email
email.send();
```

My problem is, when I execute this application from Eclipse, I get email sent with attachment without any issues. But when i deploy the application to Tomcat server (I have

tried both version 5 & 6 no joy), the e-mail is sent with below content;

```
------=_Part_0_25002283.1275298567928
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

testing


Regards,

los

------=_Part_0_25002283.1275298567928
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="doc.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
 filename="doc.pdf"
Content-Description: Testing attach
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.......
CnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0KMTE2DQolJUVPRg0K
------=_Part_0_25002283.1275298567928--
```

One thing also I have noticed is, the header information donot show TO and Subject values. Hmm pretty wierd. 
I have to point out that, above is not generated of DEBUG, it is the actual message recieved in my outlook client.

Can someone help me please!

**Update**: The application is pretty simple. Attachment a Part and text message as a seperate part also.

```
   public final void Email(String from, String to, String cc,
          String subject, String message, String doc, String bcc) {

      MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();

    try {

        if (!(doc == null)) {
                     EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
                     attachment.setURL(new URL("http://cashew.org/doc.pdf"));
         attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
         attachment.setDescription("Testing attach");
         attachment.setName("doc.pdf");
                     email.attach(attachment);  
        }


        email.setHostName("mail.cashew.com");

        // [ Set Header details
        email.setTo(getAddress(to));
        email.setFrom(from);
        email.setSubject(subject);


        if (!(cc == null)) {
              eEmail.setCc(getAddress(cc));
        }

        if (!(bcc == null)) {
            email.setBcc(getAddress(bcc));
        }

        email.setMsg(message);

        email.send();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Do anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: I don't think you show us everything.  For example I don't see code for the first part of your multipart message.

Comment: @Alexander - method for performing the e-mail send shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was the issue](http://brightdadson.blogspot.com/2010/06/if-you-are-working-on-spring-web.html)

> **Causes**: The described issue is caused by transitive dependencies of
>   Apache CXF 2 or Axiom.
>
> **SOLUTION**: To resolve this issue, exclude geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec
>   from the build, and just rely on javax's mail-1.4.x.jar.
>
> ```
>     <!--For Apache CXF 2 Project: Do this Exclude-->
> <dependency>    
>   <groupid>org.apache.cxf</groupid>   
>   <artifactid>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactid>    
>   <version>2.2.6</version>    
>     <exclusions>        
>       <exclusion>            
>        <groupid>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupid>            
>        <artifactid>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactid>        
>       </exclusion>
>      <exclusion> 
>       <groupid>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupid> 
>       <artifactid>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactid>
>      </exclusion>    
>  </exclusions>
> </dependency>
>
> <!--For Axis2 Project with Axiom Dependency: Do this Exclude-->
> <dependency>  
>   <groupid>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupid>  
>   <artifactid>axiom-api</artifactid>  
>   <version>1.2.8</version>  
>     <exclusions>       
>      <exclusion> 
>       <groupid>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupid> 
>       <artifactid>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactid>
>      </exclusion>
>      <exclusion>
>       <groupid>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupid> 
>       <artifactid>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactid>
>      </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> ```